# Backup files to Google Cloud via Python and Google-API produces duplicate files

Tags: python, file, google-cloud-platform, duplicates

I want to backup files from local disc to Google-Drive-Cloud using a Python program and the Google API.
In general it works. I have access to my Google account via the API and the files are copied.

But I don't want to to copy files to the Cloud which are already there (with the same filename!).

The problem:
Some files (almost all files) will be copied twice or more to the cloud.And I have no idea after spending a lot of time for research to solve this behavior.

Maybe I get a hint in this forum. Now here comes the Python program:

```py
import os
import os.path
import time         # Für die Messung der verstrichenene Zeit



from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from datetime import datetime           # Für die Messung der verstrichenene Zeit


#SCOPES
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

start = datetime.now() # Für die Messung der Zeitdauer


creds = None
filenumber = 0



# #########################
# ##### Authentication ####
# #########################

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                #'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                ' -- here is the json file --', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())





# ---------------------------------- Keyboard --------------------------------------------------------

anz_files_copied = 0

# ####################################
# ########## P F A D E ###############   4 x den Zielpfad ändern !!
# ####################################
# Your source folder path
source_folder = r"d:\sync2\_nach_Instrumenten_sortiert"
source_folder = os.path.join(source_folder,"Keyboard")
    
# Destination folder path on Google Drive
destination_folder_path = "Noten_sortiert_nach_Instrumenten/Keyboard"

try:
    service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

    # Destination: Find or create the "Noten_sortiert_nach_Instrumenten" folder
    folder_query = "name='Noten_sortiert_nach_Instrumenten' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    response = service.files().list(q=folder_query, spaces='drive').execute()
    
    if not response['files']:
        print("Der Ordner muss erst noch erzeugt werden !")
        folder_metadata = {
            "name": "Noten_sortiert_nach_Instrumenten",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
        }
        folder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields="id").execute()
        backup_folder_id = folder.get('id')
    else:
        backup_folder_id = response['files'][0]['id']
        print("Der Ordner existiert bereits!")


    # Find or create the subfolder in destination
    subfolder_query = f"'{backup_folder_id}' in parents and name='Keyboard' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    subfolder_response = service.files().list(q=subfolder_query, spaces='drive').execute()

    if not subfolder_response['files']:
        print("Der Unterordner muss erst noch erzeugt werden !")
        subfolder_metadata = {
            "name": "Keyboard",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
            "parents": [backup_folder_id]
        }
        subfolder = service.files().create(body=subfolder_metadata, fields="id").execute()
        folder_id = subfolder.get('id')
    else:
        folder_id = subfolder_response['files'][0]['id']
        print("Der Unterordner existiert bereits!")



    # List files in the source folder
    local_files = os.listdir(source_folder)
    # Check if files are already on Google Drive
    drive_files = service.files().list(
        q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents",
        fields="files(name)"        
    ).execute()
    
    
    drive_filenames = [file['name'] for file in drive_files.get('files', [])]
    for file in local_files:
        print("Analysiere file: " , file)
        if file not in drive_filenames:
            print("scheint noch nicht in der Cloud zu sein!")
            file_metadata = {
                "name": file,
                "parents": [folder_id]
            }
            media = MediaFileUpload(os.path.join(source_folder, file))
            upload_file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                 media_body=media,
                                                 fields="id").execute()

            filenumber = filenumber + 1
            print("File Nr.",filenumber,". Backed up file: " + file)
            anz_files_copied = anz_files_copied + 1

        else:
            print("File already exists on Google Drive: " + file)

except HttpError as err:
    print("Error: " + str(err))

print("Anzahl Dateien kopiert : ",anz_files_copied)
```

I repeated the python-program several times. I expect, that after the first start, no further files will be copied (because within the first start all files are already copied).